# The theme that CiviCRM uses is the one!

Tags: theme, mobile

We've been looking for simple, mobile-first, CiviCRM friendly theme, to dovetail with a modernized version of our non-Drupal front end. The CiviCRM  site looks swell, y'all! I'm sure there were some custom moves made, but would you mind telling what you started with if anyone is around who knows?

Gratefully,

Clay Kilgore 
San Francisco

Comment: suggest you change the Question title to one that can be answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not work on the site, but looking at the source code from View Source in the browser, it looks like the [Bootstrap theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) was the main theme, and then they created a subtheme called "civicrm_bootstrap" off of that.

[image: Line of code from theme]
[image: More code]

Comment: Wow, thanks for being so great, Mr. Hutchinson!

Comment: Glad to help.  I don't know how familiar you are with the Stack Exchange format, but if this is the answer you were looking for, then make sure to click the checkmark and accept it as the answer (and upvote it too).